# ColdFusion: cfselect and disabled attribute from variable

Tags: select, coldfusion, disabled-control

Here is my `cfselect`:

```
<cfselect
    name="UrgencyId"
    query="GetUrgencies"
    value="id"
    display="Urgency"
    selected="#issue.UrgencyId#">
</cfselect>
```

It works well except I do not know how to make it disabled according to variable value.

If I do so, it appears disabled:

```
<cfselect
    name="UrgencyId"
    query="GetUrgencies"
    value="id"
    display="Urgency"
    selected="#issue.UrgencyId#"
    disabled="disabled">
</cfselect>
```

But when I try to add cfif, an error occurs (ok, I see that layout is wrong):

```
<cfselect
    name="UrgencyId"
    query="GetUrgencies"
    value="id"
    display="Urgency"
    selected="#issue.UrgencyId#"
    <cfif true>disabled="disabled"</cfif>>
</cfselect>
```

Ok, I try to use a variable:

```
<cfset dsbl="disabled='disabled'">
<cfselect
    name="UrgencyId"
    query="GetUrgencies"
    value="id"
    display="Urgency"
    selected="#issue.UrgencyId#"
    #dsbl#>
</cfselect>
```

and get an error:

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 47 at column 139. 
 ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
#
```

I have read that `cfselect` has an `enabled` attribute which acts opposite to `disabled` HTML attribute. So I tried this:

```
<cfselect enabled="no">
<cfselect enabled="false">
<cfselect enabled=no>
<cfselect enabled=false>
```

all this didn't disable my dropdown.

Comment: Paul - you should not use `cfform` or any of the related tags, or any of the client side (UI, AJAX, etc) stuff in ColdFusion. There are limitations to each that developers usually hit fairly quickly. Instead, take the time to learn how do this kind of stuff using regular HTML forms and javaScript such as jQuery. Not only will you not be limited by `cfform`, but you will be learning skills you can easily translate into other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend not using `cfform` because it tends to do a lot more harm than good, with that being said you can use an `attributeCollection` to get this working.

```
<cfset stSelect = {
    name = 'UrgencyId',
    query = 'GetUrgencies',
    value = 'id',
    display = 'Urgency'
} />
<cfif boxShouldBeDisabled>
  <cfset stSelect.disabled = 'disabled' />
</cfif>

<cfselect attributeCollection="#stSelect#">
</cfselect>
```

You don't specify your ColdFusion version, but the above code should work on CF8 or greater and was tested on CF10.

Not using `cfform` your code would look like. It's definitely not as clean looking, but it enables you to not use `cfform`

```
<select name="UrgencyId">
  <cfloop query="GetUrgencies">
    <option value="#GetUrgencies.id#"<cfif issue.UrgencyID EQ GetUrgencies.id> selected="selected"</cfif><cfif shouldbeDisabled> disabled="disabled"</cfif>>#GetUrgencies.Urgency#</option>
  </cfloop>
</select>
```

Comment: Not using `cfform` tag has a drawback: you will have to write all the validations manually.

Comment: 1. cfform doesn't do server-side validation, so you still need to.

Comment: 2. **Everything** cfform does can be done _better_ by [other software](http://carehart.org/cf411/#form).

Comment: @Paul don't rely on `cfform` validation...it is not as good as rolling yoru own. You want easy validation? check out ValidateThis - http://www.validatethis.org/

Comment: I am very upset. In a past few days in which I learn Coldfusion I noticed one trend: There are some things in CF that promise enhancements and improvements, but nobody uses them preferring a classical way and hand-made controls.

Comment: CF does not promise enhancements and improvements on form controls and such. It tries to make it easier, and, unless you have a very simple application, it does. However, as I noted, developers typically hit the limitations of the functionality very quickly. Learning all the tips and 'tricks' of `cfform` will make you a better ColdFusion developer, but learning how to do those same 'tricks' using jQuery or some other JavaScript library will make you a better web developer. You can use jQuery in ANY application, ColdFusion, PHP, Rails, Grails, etc.

Comment: This seems to be coming up a lot lately and I recently found a pretty good blog about it from Ben Forta. Read this - http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense. Make sure you read it because the title is a bit mis-leading.